# How can I send values from multiple forms in an Ext.Ajax.request?

Tags: ajax, extjs

I have multiple forms, and I want to pass the values from all of them in  a single `Ext.Ajax.request` call. How can I do this?

```
var forme1 = this.form1.getForm().getFieldValues();
var forme2 = this.form2.getForm().getFieldValues();
var forme3 = this.form3.getForm().getFieldValues();
var forme=new Array(forme1,forme2,forme3);
Ext.Ajax.request(
    {
        url: 'save.php',
        params: forme
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Ext.apply to merge the form value objects together:

```
var values = this.form1.getForm().getFieldValues();
Ext.apply(values, this.form2.getForm().getFieldValues());
Ext.apply(values, this.form3.getForm().getFieldValues());

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'save.php',
    params: values
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a object

```
var forme1 = this.form1.getForm().getFieldValues();
var forme2 = this.form2.getForm().getFieldValues();
var forme3 = this.form3.getForm().getFieldValues();
var forme  = Ext.Object.merge(forme1,forme2,forme3);

Ext.Ajax.request(
    {
        url: 'save.php',
        params: forme
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a single FormPanel with multiple fieldsets in if all the values need to be submitted in a single request.  This way Ext does a lot of the work for you.

otherwise you will need to do something like this.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'SomeUrl',
    params: Ext.encode({
        formData1: myForm1.getValues(),
        formData2: myForm2.getValues(),
        formData3: myForm3.getValues(),
    }),
    method: 'POST'
    ...
})
```